# Is pull up resistor for I2C address pin needed or can it be connected directly to VDD

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, i2c

To avoid an address conflict, I need to connect an SHT31's address pin to high.
The [datasheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Sensirion%20PDFs/HT_DS_SHT3x_DIS.pdf), doesn't specify if I need any resistors for this or if it has to go directly to VDD. I'm concerned about power consumption since it is a battery powered device.
Is it ok to connect it directly and if not, what value of resistor must be used to obtain the high address while consuming little power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the datasheet does not specify any requirement, it can be directly connected to VDD.

So a resistor is not necessary. However, nothing prevents putting a resistor to pull the pin up. It does not make much difference, as long as the resistor has a reasonable value, like between 0 ohms and 100 kohms.

Comment: Can I assume that no extra power will be consumed than if there was a resistor?

Comment: The datasheet does not indicate anything about what kind of leakage currents would be. It is possible to use a resistor just as well, it does not matter much. If there is very little leakage current, there would be very little voltage drop over a resistor.

Answer (score 2):

Logic low is GND and logic high is VCC. No resistor needed.

If you would add a resistor (with a large value) to VCC, a small current would lower the voltage at the pin and it would no longer be at logic high.

Comment: I understand there would be a drop due to the resistor, but I'm concerned of the current through the pin if I don't limit it with the resistor

Comment: I think the rationale is, if there _was_ a significant current, and you limited it with a resistor, then the pin wouldn't be high any more. Therefore it's very unlikely that the chip would be designed that way, especially after boasting its microamp-range idle current.

Comment: @mmvgm1 The input impedance will probably be in the M\$\Omega\$-range. So the current will be very small already. Even adding some k\$\Omega\$-resistor will not change the current much. But a to large resistor will change your pulled-up pin to logic low.

Answer (score 2):

Using a resistor to pull up the pin, will make the pull-up weaker (both adding the resistor and the need of longer traces) and the pin will be vulnerable to noise (for example if a antenna radiates nearby, it will disrupt the pull up, and it may cause the pin to read 0 instead of 1).

And yes, it will draw a little bit of current, but usually the pin is already some Mohms of input impedance, so a little current is drawn anyway.

So you have to trade between power consumption (if you do not add a resistor) and noise tolerance, higher price, less space (if you add a resistor)

If your IC has this option, pull down the pin instead of High. It will solve all the above issues.

Comment: How would the use of resistor or no resistor will affect the power consumption - in any significant way that is? How would it have any effect if it is a pull-up or pull-down to solve any issues (assuming there are any issues)?

Comment: It will not change the power consumption in any significant way.